# How to debug a Kotlin/Native application in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin-native

I am trying to debug my Kotlin/Native (linuxX64) application in IntelliJ but I can't find a way to do it.

What I tried:

Press the play button
[image: play button]

Then, click "Debug 'runDebugExecutableNa...'"

Gradle starts building, the application starts, but the breakpoints don't work (it never stops executing, the application just goes from start to end without interruption).

I have tried removing the Run Configuration as well as restarting the IDE, but no luck.
I also tried following this guide: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-get-started.html#build-and-run-the-application

But it does not show me that "native.native-project | Debug" run configuration which I assume is added by IntelliJ automatically.

The drop down only contains "Current File" and the "runDebugExecutableNative" Gradle task. Current File does not allow me to click any of the play/debug buttons, and the Gradle task obviously does not actually debug the application.

I remember having done this before but when I tried it in an older project, it didn't work either.

I'm kind of clueless here. I expected IntelliJ to be fully able to debug Kotlin/Native applications, not just JVM.